# Splitting DataFrame in 2 based on a columns value

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have a dataset that I am trying to split into 2 smaller dataframes called test and train. The original dataset has two columns "patient_nbr" and "encounter_id". These columns all have 6 digit values.

How can I go through this dataframe, and add up all the digits in those two columns. For example, if in the first row of the dataframe the values are 123456 and 123456, I need to add 1+2+3+4+5+6+1+2+3+4+5+6. The sum is used to determine if that row goes into test or train. If it is even, test. If it is odd, train.

Below is what I tried. But it is so slow. I turned the two columns I need into two numpy arrays in order to break down and add up the digits. I added those numpy arrays to get one, and looped through that to get determine which dataframe it should go in.

```py
with ZipFile('dataset_diabetes.zip') as zf:
    with zf.open('dataset_diabetes/diabetic_data.csv','r') as f:
        df = pd.read_csv(f)

nums1 = []
nums2 = []

encounters = df["encounter_id"].values
for i in range(len(encounters)):
    result = 0
    while encounters[i] > 0:
        rem = encounters[i] % 10
        result = result + rem
        encounters[i] = int(encounters[i]/10)
    nums1.append(result)

patients = df["patient_nbr"].values
for i in range(len(patients)):
    result = 0
    while patients[i] > 0:
        rem = patients[i] % 10
        result = result + rem
        patients[i] = int(patients[i]/10)
    nums2.append(result)

nums = np.asarray(nums1) + np.asarray(nums2)
df["num"] = nums

# nums = df["num"].values

train = pd.DataFrame()
test = pd.DataFrame()

for i in range(len(nums)):
    if int(nums[i] % 2) == 0:
        # goes to train
        train.append(df.iloc[i])
    else:
        # goes to test
        test.append(df.iloc[i])
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do it by playing with `astype` to go from `int` to `str` to `float`, `sum` both columns over the row once string (like concatenate both strings), then `str.split` and expand the string, and `sum` again per row after selecting the right columns and change the type of each digit as float.

```
#dummy example
df = pd.DataFrame({'patient_nbr':[123456, 123457, 123458],
                   'encounter_id':[123456, 123456, 123457]})

#create num
df['num'] = df[['patient_nbr', 'encounter_id']].astype(str).sum(axis=1)\
              .astype(str).str.split('', expand=True)\
              .loc[:,1:12].astype(float).sum(axis=1)

print (df)
   patient_nbr  encounter_id   num
0       123456        123456  42.0
1       123457        123456  43.0
2       123458        123457  45.0
```

then use this column to create a mask with even as False and odd as True

```
mask = (df['num']%2).astype(bool)
train = df.loc[~mask, :] #train is the even
test = df.loc[mask, :] #test is the odd
print (test)
   patient_nbr  encounter_id   num
1       123457        123456  43.0
2       123458        123457  45.0
```